# Loops in SCSS - multiple variables and different values

Tags: css, loops, sass

I want to make loop using multiple variables and different values. I wrote that .scss code:

```
// Margin variabels
$margin-dynamic: 15px !default;
$margin-auto: 0 auto !default;
$margin-none: 0 !default;

// Dynamic margin @mixin
@mixin margin-classes($margin-dynamic-classes) {
    @each $margins in $margin-dynamic-classes {
        .margin-#{$margins} {
            margin-#{$margins}: $margin-dynamic !important;
        }
        .margin-duble-#{$margins} {
            margin-#{$margins}: ($margin-dynamic * 2) !important;
        }
        .margin-minus-#{$margins} {
            margin-#{$margins}: -#{$margin-dynamic} !important;
        }
    }
}

@include margin-classes($margin-dynamic-classes:top right bottom left);

// Static margin
.margin-auto {
    margin: $margin-auto;
}

.margin-none {
    margin: $margin-none;
}
```

I want to add `.margin-auto` and `.margin-none` to the loop, but i don't know how to do that.

A same problem I'm having with that variables:

```
// Display variabels
$display-block: block !default;
$display-inline-block: inline-#{$display-block} !default;
$display-inline: inline !default;
$display-table: table !default;
$display-table-cell: #{$display-table}-cell !default;
$display-none: none !default;

// Display
.display-block {
    display: $display-block;
}
.display-inline-block {
    display: $display-inline-block;
}
.display-inline {
    display: $display-inline;
}
.display-table {
    display: $display-table;
}
.display-table-cell {
    display: $display-table;
}
.display-none {
    display: $display-none;
}
```

I'm newbe in SASS, so I would appreciate clarification on this.

Comment: If you have 2 different questions, you need to ask them separately.

Comment: I didn't want to duplicate question. Do I have to do this ?

Comment: They're not duplicates.  For your first question, I don't know why you'd want to have those extra classes inside of a loop at all.  Your second question doesn't have any loops in it (nor an attempt to make one) and makes no sense anyway (why would you want to do this?).

Comment: I want to made margin generator for my website project. My secend question is really contributes with first - I want to know how to make loop using multiple variables with different values.

Comment: You haven't explained why you want the margin generation *inside* of the loop because they look pretty static to me (unless you want to have a lot of them repeated every time you call your mixin?).  Your second question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034750/access-the-iterator-and-append-it-to-variable-name-in-sass

Comment: I'm now having solution of my problem. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: You can check display function here http://codepen.io/MagicJoseph/pen/igFBe.scss

Comment: Check how it works after few updates. https://gist.github.com/MagicJoseph/daf007055d474be10062